# Count Discussion Board Posts without replies

Tags: 2010, discussion-board

I am working on building a trouble ticket system using a SharePoint 2010 discussion board as the foundation. How do I get a serial number (ID) for the posts and not count the replies. Currently I see the ID adds all the replies on. I need a serial number for the tickets as they come in.

Reason for the discussion board, is we are trying to remove emailing the users with outlook. A lot of troubleshooting knowledge is lost because things get lost in emails. This way all correspondence with the customer will stay within the site and the users involved will receive an email alert.

If anyone knows of a better solution that would be great. I do have farm level access, however I am trying hard to not do to much custom work since we are about to upgrade to 2016 in about 9 months.